# How to transfer files between Ubuntu servers so that A logs to B with key and gets the file without B logging to A?

Tags: ubuntu, scp

1. I have a key on machine B that with it can log to machine A
2. on machine A I can run a script to create archive dump from database
3. Now I wish to get this archive from A back to B

PROBLEM! I want to ONLY HAVE ONE KEY file on machine B to connect to machine A and avoid having another key on machine A to connect back to machine B

Im trying to do this with scp command,

```
scp -i key_file `date +"%m-%d-%y".gz` ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:`date +"%m-%d-%y".gz`
```

Problem here is that while I am logged into machine B, and I run this I need to have another key_file on
machine A.

Could I achieve this somehow by only having one key on machine B, use that to operate in machine A and get the file out without having another key?

I want to limit security threats and not have two keys so that if machine A gets jacked it wont have access to B.

Comment: You're running the scp command from computer B, right? But the scp command is copying a date.gz file to computer A? What is the behavior you see with this command?

Comment: i make connection from B to A with ssh -i command, and then im on computer A. While on A I make dump and now want to trasnfer it back to B but do it without using any key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can `ssh` into computer A from computer B, then you can do an `scp` command from computer B to retrieve the file from computer A back to computer B, as well. Run this command from computer B:

`scp -i your_key computerA@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/path_to_file_in_comp_A/file /path_in_comp_B/`

where you need to substitute the correct key file, usernames, ip addresses, and paths to the command.